# How to implement thousand separator for a given text which contains numerical value? Cast and Varchar_format is not working

Tags: db2, db2-400, db2-luw

I need to show   3456789 as 34,56,789 in the output of below select query in db2

SELECT
' RUN TIME: ' CONCAT CURRENT_TIME CONCAT SPACE(39) CONCAT 'PROCESS' CONCAT SPACE(44) CONCAT '3456789'
FROM
sysibm.sysdummy1 WITH UR;

Current Output is: RUN TIME: 14.13.24                                       PROCESS                                            3456689

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'3456789'` is already a string...

Assuming your data actually starts out numeric, take a look at `varchar_format()`

```
SELECT ' RUN TIME: ' CONCAT CURRENT_TIME 
  CONCAT SPACE(39) CONCAT 'PROCESS' CONCAT SPACE(44) 
  CONCAT varchar_format(3456789,'9,999,999') 
FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 WITH UR;
```

Note it's usually a bad practice to do this formatting in the DB, it's usually best left to the UI.

Comment: I am getting following error SQL Error [22007]: Format string "9,999,999" is not valid for the "SYSIBM.VARCHAR_FORMAT" function.. SQLCODE=-20447, SQLSTATE=22007, DRIVER=4.21.29

Comment: @Robin what platform and version of Db2?  Works for me on Db2 for IBM i 7.4.